# Error with enzyme when using shallow on a connected component: "Shallow rendering works only with custom components"

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have a React component, connected with redux :

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    [...]
}

export default connect((state) => ({
    [...]
}))(LoginForm);
```

I'm trying to test it with Jest and Enzyme.
When I use **shallow()** on the wrappedcomponent everything is working fine:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm.WrappedComponent />);
```

But when I try **shallow()** on the connected component, I'm geting an error:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<LoginForm />);

ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was `object`.
```

I was expecting shallow to render *Connect(LoginForm)* and to complain about the missing store.
Any Idea what I'm missing / doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't test the connected component, test the actual component and mock its props for a meaningful unit tests. Otherwise you're unit testing connect, which should work out of the box as expected. If you really want some sort of integration test of the connected component, use `mount()` and google how to mock the redux store etc. for enzyme.

Comment: Thank you @timotgl, this is already how I'm testing my components. In addition I wanted to be able to test the connected component in order to get 100% code coverage. Otherwise I'm not testing mapStateToProps (check the presence of props on the connected component). For example for this specific component, I'm stuck at 95% code coverage.

Comment: you can test mapStateToProps independently if you export it. You just need to mock any selectors that are used inside (jest.mock() for example).